# Keyboard events in IE9 html explorer bar

Tags: internet-explorer-9

- **Claim:** Keyboard events aren't dispatched in IE9 html explorer bars.
- **Proof:** Try running the HTML below in an IE9 html explorer bar.
- **Expected:** an alert should be shown after pressing a key anywhere on the document (of the explorer bar - note that this alert is shown by loading this HTML into a normal IE9 tab).
- **Actual:** nothing happens.
- **The question is:** can an IE9 html explorer bar be configured to enable keyboard event handling?

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>IE9</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.js"></script>    
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert("before event registration");
            $(document).keydown(function() { alert("inside event handler"); });
        }); 
        </script>    
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After re-checking the issue on my colleagues' machines I found out that it doesn't reproduce there - it's specific to my machine and sounds like a "glitch". That made me happy.